# What notify signal for change output path in 3Ds MAX

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I need catch when output path has been changed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEKGz.png).
I try use NOTIFY_RENDPARAM_CHANGED, but it work only after close window "render setup".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Render Setup dialog is pretty crappy in this regard. You'll see the value is not even available in MAXScript until you close the dialog. Most of this dialog's state is held in UI only, and may hark back to extremely old versions where perhaps it was possible to "cancel" changes. If you look at `Interface7` you'll see there is a `CancelRenderDialog` interface, which is no longer used. Test by calling `CommitRenderDialogParameters` from the same interface -- that should also update and notify, and is probably the earliest time you can know the value is being stored into the scene.